# Configuring a Python Script on Windows without internet

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that I want to move a to Windows Server but the machine is not connected to the internet.

Having tried various methods I'm hoping to get some advice.

This is what I've tried:

On the development machine I have used *pip freeze > requirements.txt* to create the requirements file, then *pip download -r requirements.txt* to download all the required packaged, 10 in total.

Both machines are running Python 3.7 and are Windows 64bit.

I created a virtual environment on the target machine copy all the *.whl files, the requirements and the script to a local folder on there.

Then using the terminal go into the virtual machine and from there have tried various commands to try install the downloaded requirements.

These have included:

*pip install --no-index --find-links R:\folder\folder -r requirements.txt*

*pip install --no-index --find-links -r  R:/folder/folder/requirements.txt*

*pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links file:///folder/packages*

When I've tried various combinations of this with double slashes etc, it either says it cannot locate the requirements file or it starts with the first one numpy and says it cannot locate the correct version which is should as it's been downloaded and is there.

Appreciate any thoughts...

Thanks

Comment: If they are both running the same Python, have you considered just copying the `Python37` directory in its entirety (wherever you put it) to the other machine?

Comment: I had thought about that what wasn't sure if it would 'upset' anything...

Comment: As long as they are the same version, it should be just fine.